# PWA ICON not showing on home screen of Iphone until restart or second add

Tags: iphone, icons, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I have a PWA operating at 'https://www.ajcproperties.com'.  On an iphone, when I 'add to home screen' the first time, there is no icon.  However, the iphone behaves as if the icon was added.

As debug, I observe that adding the PWA to the home screen results in increasing the number of home-screen pages, but doesn't place the icon on any home-screen page [the last page is blank].

If I restart the phone, the icon appears on the last page.

If I add to home-screen a second time, the icon appears on the last page.  but the device believes there are two apps... I have to remove twice.

```
manifest.json
{
  "short_name": "AJC",
  "name": "AJC Properties",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "AJC_favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }, {
      "src": "/images/AJC_LogoLG_FINAL_SQUARE_64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "/images/AJC_LogoLG_FINAL_SQUARE_192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "/images/AJC_LogoLG_FINAL_SQUARE_512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I expect adding once results in the Icon on the home-screen immediately.  Apparently something in my set-up is wrong, but gets cleaned up with a restart or a second add.

Comment: Have you tried to check the guidelines of a valid chrome app scenario in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804917/add-to-home-screen-not-showing-up-pwa)?

Comment: I checked on those things.  I ran lighthouse on the site and pass as a PWA.  It seems this is iphone specific and perhaps index.html/manifest.json specific... but i'm guessing at the moment.  The fact that things cleanup after a restart throws me off.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a PWA specific thing. I'm building a regular app on Xcode 10.1 and when I do a first-install of to my XS phone I get the same symptoms as you

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for that.  I'll modify the answer to reflect it is a more general problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug on iOS.  It is a special case of adding an app [whether PWA or native].  In the case of a PWA, when the last home page is full of icons.  Upon selecting add to home screen, the device creates a new page for icons, but does not place the icon on the screen.  A power cycle will reveal that the app was indeed added.